# C++ Debugging on VSCode with makefile

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

as the title suggests, I am trying to debug a C++ program on my mac m2 using Makefile Tools extension on VSCode.

`tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build & debug tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++14",
                "-I/src",
                "-lgtest",
                "-o",
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-12 build active file",
            "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-12",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

`settings.json`

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "vector": "cpp",
        "__bit_reference": "cpp",
        "__hash_table": "cpp",
        "__split_buffer": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "deque": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "unordered_map": "cpp",
        "filesystem": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp"
    },
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",
    "makefile.panel.visibility": null,
    "makefile.launchConfigurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart",
            "binaryPath": "/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn",
            "binaryArgs": [
                "-d -n 3 -V 3730 datasets/NYCoordsTest_graph.txt datasets/NY_knnqueries.txt"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "makefile.configurations": [

        {
            "name":"streetsmart configuration",
            "makeArgs": ["distFunc=L2"]
        }

    ]
}
```

`launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
          "label": "build-all",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "main_knn distFunc=L2",
        }
      ],
      "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/knn",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
      ],
      
      
      
}
```

Using the configuration above, I get the following weird error when I am trying to debug.

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn",target-name="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn",host-name="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn"
Loaded '/usr/lib/dyld'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn'. Symbols loaded.
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn",target-name="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn",host-name="/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn"
Loaded '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc@12/12.3.0/lib/gcc/12/libstdc++.6.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc@12/12.3.0/lib/gcc/12/libgcc_s.1.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwindirectory.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/liboah.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
=thread-selected,id="1"
L2
/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn: illegal option --
The program '/Users/dinosaur/streetsmart/knn' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

The program runs fine if I click run instead of debug, so I cannot understand where the error is. I searched for hours to find something similar to that illegal option, but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The last line means that `knn` was executed and that it exited with error code zero (which by convention means success). Looks like your program does get executed after all.

Comment: That’s what I thought at first, but nothing get printed and I can’t see variables at breakpoints